# Enable command line audit logging in docker container - kubernetes

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, logging, kubernetes

Hope you can help.

I am trying to enable audit logging in a docker container so if anybody `kubectl exec` to a docker container and runs any commands, then those commands get logged and we can view them in `kubectl logs` and capture with `fluentd` for example.

An option with adding the following line to `/etc/profile` of a container works for `root` but not for a `non-root` user as `/proc/1/fd/1` is owned and writable by only `root` user and changing ownership or permissions, is not an option, unfortunately.

```
trap 'echo "$USER":"$BASH_COMMAND" >> /proc/1/fd/1' DEBUG
```

So far have tried the following:

- A working option would be to run the container as a `non-root`, but unfortunately this is not an option
- Option with just changing permissions/ownership doesn't change permissions/ownership
- Also adding `mesg y` to `/etc/profile` to allow access to root's didn't work either as when doing `su - non-root` the permission gets denied (`mesg: cannot open /dev/pts/2: Permission denied`) - cannot change the permission
- An option with adding a special file and trying to redirect the logs from there didn't work either, still the permission gets denied. For example:

```
mkfifo -m 666 /tmp/logpipe  #create the special file
trap 'echo "$USER":"$BASH_COMMAND" <> /tmp/logpipe > /proc/1/fd/1' DEBUG  # in /etc/profile
```

- Changing to `trap 'echo "$USER":"$BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG` won't work either as the logs need to go to `/proc/1/fd/1` in case of docker

How would you enable command line audit logging in docker container or workaround the `/proc/1/fd/1` permission issue for `non-root` in a container run as `root` user?

Any ideas highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, came across my own question :D
So, [Falco](https://falco.org/) can be used as a HIDS (Host-based intrusion detection system), which will alert on any unusual activity based on rules defined in Flaco configuration. This can be deployed as a Deamonset (privileged) or directly on nodes.